# Puppeteer Answer Screen Share Popup

Tags: google-chrome, popup, puppeteer

Is there any way I can answer the "Share your screen" popup with Puppeteer?
I have to just choose "Screen 1" and click the button "Share".

I have tried using `page.keyboard.press('Tab')` and `page.keyboard.press('Enter')` but that just cannot act on the popup.
I have also tried `page.on('popup', function)` and `page.on('dialog', function)` with no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Popup]